# Extract integer from data object received from UDP stream

Tags: python, udp, extract

I'm receiving data from a *UDP* stream sent from a database that forwards its incoming data to a Python script.

I'm using the following code to receive the data:

```py
import socket

UDP_IP = "localhost"
UDP_PORT = 5060
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

while True:
   data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
   print (data)
```

The data is returned as a *byte-like object* (please correct me if I'm wrong). Printing the data variable would look something like this:

```
b'nulldata,country=swe,region=europe,tag=tagged value=10 1505893007463590886'
```

But could also look like this depending on what data is sent from the server:

```
b'nulldata,country=swe,region=europe,tag=tagged value=4123.4331,value2=123.5123, 1505893008892590551'
```

What would be the most efficient way of extracting the numeric value after `value=` and `value2=` as well as the *id* (1505893008892590551) and storing it in a dictionary or list that would look something like this?

```
[1505893008892590551, 4123.4331, 123.5123]
```

or

```
{'ID': 1505893008892590551, 'Value': 4123.4331, 'Value2': 123.5123}
```

A method that would be generic and would work even if I added more values would be preferred!

Answer (score 0):

> The data is returned as a "byte-like object"

Yes it is. In Python 2, however, this is the same as ordinary string. To get a string in Python 3, do `b'my text'.decode()`.

Asuming then

```
s1 = 'nulldata,country=swe,region=europe,tag=tagged value=10 1505893007463590886'
s2 = 'nulldata,country=swe,region=europe,tag=tagged value=4123.4331,value2=123.5123, 1505893008892590551'
```

(both strings)

## Use regex

Your regex that matches both of your inputs may look like

```
pattern = re.compile(r'''
    value=(?P<Value>[0-9.]+)            # capture `value`
    (?:,value2=(?P<Value2>[0-9.]+))?    # optionally capture `value2`
    ,?\                                 # optional comma and a space
    (?P<ID>\d+)$                        # capture `id` at the end 
    ''', re.VERBOSE)
```

Thinks to notice:

- verbose regex – whitespaces and comments are ignored
- named capture group `(?P<name>pattern)`
- non capturing group `(?:pattern)` that is also optional (question mark after that)

Dictionary then can be accessed with `groupdict`:

```
>>> re.search(pattern, s1).groupdict()
{'ID': '1505893007463590886', 'Value2': None, 'Value': '10'}
>>> re.search(pattern, s2).groupdict()
{'ID': '1505893008892590551', 'Value2': '123.5123', 'Value': '4123.4331'}
```